# How do I find out what the ErrorMessage parameters are for a validation block?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm looking at an example MVC project and working through the code. The models have validation blocks on them and while they're easy enough to read, like this one...

```
    ' 

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = _
          "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    '
```

...I can't find a list of the parameters that are available to the `ErrorMessage`.

In the example `"The {0} must be at least {2} characters long."` I can guess at what `{0}` and `{2}` refer to, but if I want to write code like this I need more concrete documentation.

I just can't manage to find it.

Comment: This might help a little bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193145/substitution-arguments-in-validationattribute-errormessage

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the documentation either.
However:
The {0} index is the display name of property, {1} is the MaximumLength, {2} is the MinimumLength.